# symfony2 adjacency list model use with Forms

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, hierarchical-data

I have a self referencing table as covered in the doctrine documentation (which is already in heavy use throughout the application and therefore changing to nested tree isn't a current option).

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.0.x/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-self-referencing

The table structure looks like this:

```
+----+----------+--------+
| id | parentID |  Name  |
+----+----------+--------+
|  1 |     null | Name 1 |
|  2 |        1 | Name 2 |
|  3 |        1 | Name 3 |
|  4 |        2 | Name 4 | 
|  5 |        1 | Name 5 |
--------------------------
```

Up until now in our forms we've been using the entire entities content our form, ie

```
        $builder->add('hierarchyid', 'entity', array(
            'class' => 'AcmeTestBundle:Hierarchies')
```

Which works fine, but now I want to be able to amend this to set points in the table, ie something like:

```
        ->add('hierarchyid', 'entity', array(
            'class' => 'AcmeTestBundle:HierarchiesTest',
            'query_builder' => function(HierarchiesTestRepository $repo)
    {return $repo->findBy??????}
```

But I've hit a mental block how to complete this, any ideas?

One option I've considered is I already have code that builds an array collection of these entities, which is used elsewhere, but I'm unfamiliar with how I should go about implement a doctrine arraycollection in a form type.

```
private function createNodeArray($node) 
{
    $this->hierarchyArrayCollection->add($node);
    foreach ($node->getChildren() as $hierarchy)
    {
       $this->createNodeArray($hierarchy);
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone interested the solution I went with in the end was to generate an array and use choice field type rather than entity,such as this:

```
->add('hierarchyid', 'choice', array(
               'choices' => $hierarchy)
```

Answer (score 3):

`query_builder` option should return `QueryBuilder` object and I assume your `findAllById()` method returns actual data. You need to change that ;)

Other than that, you should probably add `property` option to indicate which field is to be displayed in list...

Comment: Thats prety much my issue. I can make my finaAllById method recursively execute, building the object, then then cannot pass back to a query_builder. I can't figure out how to push this back to the form. If I just return a QueryBuilder, as per a normal, such as find('2'), I wont currently return the children.

as for property, my entity is using toString to deal with this.